# How to install foo dupe-target

Tags: discussion

I'm wondering if it would be worth it to make some kind of dupe-target post for these "how to install" posts. See:

- [How install ADB and Fastboot on elementary os?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/924/how-install-adb-and-fastboot-on-elementary-os)
- [How can I install Gnome Builder IDE?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/138/how-can-i-install-gnome-builder-ide)
- [How can I install and run Minecraft?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/163/how-can-i-install-and-run-minecraft)
- https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/841/how-can-i-install-gedit
- [How can I install VBox Guest Additions?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/3/how-can-i-install-vbox-guest-additions)
- [How do I install Oracle Java JDK 8 on Freya?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/716/how-do-i-install-oracle-java-jdk-8-on-freya)
- [How to install Fish shell](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/871/how-to-install-fish-shell)
- [How install conky-manager on Freya?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/222/how-install-conky-manager-on-freya)

Are these processes similar enough that we should have a canonical post explaining how to install software on elementary OS? Maybe we can come up with a generic process like:

1. Check Software Center
2. Look for a PPA (warning about how/why PPAs can be dangerous)
3. Generic instructions/reference about building from source

Comment: I see your point. Especially all questions about apps that are directly available from default sources seem close-worthy (with linking to your mentionend canonical post). On the other hand the gedit question showed that there are more valid answers than `apt-get install`.

Answer (score 4):

Some canonical questions about software installation would be a good thing. It's maybe a little early to know what the right scope is, unless you have prior experience from other elementary OS support channels. Getting the scope of canonical questions right is not always easy: if you make them too specialized, they're rarely applicable, but if you make them too broad, they tend to be messy, so you end up having to write tailored answers to more specific questions, because the canonical question question isn't clear enough.

From prior experience with other distributions, I can see several common questions:

- I'm looking for software to do something, how do I find it?
  A: first search the software center. Then explore PPAs. As a last resort, search the web.
  Ex: subsumes [How install ADB and Fastboot on elementary os?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/924/how-install-adb-and-fastboot-on-elementary-os), https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/841/how-can-i-install-gedit (unless you interpret it as “how do I edit text?” in which case it isn't a “how to install” question)
- The software I want for isn't in elementary but exists in a PPA. Is installing a PPA for Ubuntu safe and how do I install it on elementary?
  Ex: subsumes [How can I install and run Minecraft?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/163/how-can-i-install-and-run-minecraft), [How install conky-manager on Freya?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/222/how-install-conky-manager-on-freya)
- The software I want requires more recent libraries, can I run it somehow?
  Ex: subsumes [How can I install Gnome Builder IDE?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/138/how-can-i-install-gnome-builder-ide)
- I have proprietary software that comes with a file to execute to install, how do I do it?
  (I'm not sure this one has a useful generic answer.)
- I need a program and I only have the source code, how do I build and install it?
- How do I install software on my account (I don't have administrator rights)?

This is just a list presented for discussion, please don't go and ask them serially.

Not every question on installing software fits in a generic mold. For example, [How can I install VBox Guest Additions?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/3/how-can-i-install-vbox-guest-additions) is peculiar because the software is provided in an unusual way (through the host of the VM) and the installer has some oddities that make the most obvious way of running it fail. Another case that doesn't fit a generic mold is
[How to install Fish shell](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/871/how-to-install-fish-shell), because in addition to installing the program, there's the question of changing the user's login shell.